# CKEditor: How to hide the spell checker button

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've been ruthlessly removing buttons/plugins but I just can't find how to remove the spell checker button. I've managed to remove the SCAYT plugin so that no longer shows but the spell checker button won't budge:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.resize_enabled = false;
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,addFile,Image,Table,Styles,Format,Maximize,HorizontalRule,Unlink,Blockquote,Indent,Outdent,RemoveFormat,Source,Spell';
    config.removePlugins = 'about,specialchar,scayt,spellchecker,elementspath,resize';
};
```

I've also tried adding various spelling variations to removeButtons such as SpellChecking, SpellCheck, Spelling etc. What do I need to set?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want just to **remove the button**, but keep the plugin, then just use:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Scayt';
```

As for the removing plugins, following config should do the job:

```
config.removePlugins = 'wsc,scayt';
```

Comment: "wsc" done it! Actually, `config.removeButtons = 'Scayt';` doesn't remove the button, just the item from the spell checker menu (the button remains). Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm testing right now with CKEditor 4.4.6 full build, and ```config.removeButtons = 'Scayt';``` indeed removes the button. Ensure that browser cache doesn't mess your results.

Comment: Maybe something wrong in my config then. It only seemed to remove for me when I added "wsc".

Comment: Same here, until I removed the wsc plugin, the button remained.

Comment: Scayt was preventing copy/paste.  Removing the plugin did it, and removing the button was also useful.